# symfony Cannot find the entity manager for class "App\Entity\User"

Tags: symfony, symfony5.4

After upgrade to last symfony 5.4 update, I remove user entity/repository to restart and remove all deprecations.

To recreate User entity/repository, I run :

```bash
php bin/console make:user --is-entity --with-password
# it returns
In DoctrineHelper.php line 91:
                                                              
  Cannot find the entity manager for class "App\Entity\User"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as mentionned in https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/issues/1158#issuecomment-1210446372,
add in *config/packages/doctrine.yaml* **type: attribute**  like that :

```yaml
# config/packages/doctrine.yaml
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
                type: attribute
```